# what is filled key in this example

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am creating star rating system. I got following example on plnkr. But I have one question, what is "filled" key and why we are using it.

```
var updateStars = function () {
                scope.stars = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < scope.max; i++) {
                    scope.stars.push({
                        filled2: i < scope.ratingValue
                    });
                }
            };
```

Whole example you can find with following link.

http://embed.plnkr.co/1esaGq/

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to hold information with this field => if the user filled the stars widget **above the rating Value**. it's a flag holding a boolean that holds the result of this expression.

In your html code your are iterating over this stars array and printing the literal '\u2605':

```
'<li ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-class="star" ng-click="toggle($index)">' +
            '\u2605' +
            '</li>' +
```

So basically this variable is just a boolean placeholder in your array of stars and you can decide to style it with css

Comment: If I would like to use this, how can I use this, please suggest with code.

Answer (score 1):

`filled` key is boolean flag, which decide your star css.

basically in line:

```
<ul class="rating">
    <li ng-repeat="star in stars" ng-class="star" ng-click="toggle($index)"></li>
</ul>
```

**ng-class="star"** resolve as `ng-class='filled: true/false'`. which then picks up color from below code of your css file on `true` condition:

```
.rating .filled {
    color: orangered;
}
```